# Grails - Field error disappears from parent class

Tags: validation, grails

I have the following problem:

I have a domain class called customer, with a field discount embedded.

```
    class Customer {
     ...
        String username
        Discount discount
        static constraints = { ... }
    }

    class Discount {
        Integer item1
        Integer item2
        static constraints = { item1 min:1, max:100, nullable:true }
    }
```

I have a controller, where a customer's data can be modified. The code goes something like this:

```
    def edit() {
        Customer c = Customer.findByUsername(params.userName)
        if(request.method != 'GET'){
            bindData(c, params)
            if(c.validate()) {
                //save the result
            }
        }
        println c.dump()//1
        model:[customer:c]
    }
```

Then in the edit.gsp I put the following code:

```
    ${customer.dump()}//2
    ${customer.discount.dump()}
```

Now my problem is, if I have a validation error, for example the user enters 123 for item1, I get the appropriate errors object which says that Customer bean has 1 field error on field discount.item1 when I call `println c.dump()//1`

In the edit.gsp on the other hand, the customer bean doesn't have any field errors but customer.discount has the mentioned error. This is a big inconvenience, because I want to render errors next to the fields like so:

```
    <g:renderErrors bean="${customer}" field="discount.item1"/>
```

But the customer bean doesn't have any errors, just the discount bean (therefore I don't get any errors rendered).

Has this problem occured to any of you ?

Comment: Have u tried `customer.discount` ie `<g:renderErrors bean="${customer.discount}" field="item1"/>`

Comment: Well, that works, but I am using auto-generated fields (via grails fields plugin) and I'd love to have every field using the same render logic, so I could just do:
`<f:all bean="customer"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `@Validatable` classes use functionality of spring framework's `AbstractBindingResult`, which doesn't support this usage (as far as I can tell).

However I was able to create a workaround, which could be used as a taglib to achieve the same effect:

Given two validateable classes

```
@Validateable
class TestA {
    TestB b

    static constraints = {
        b validator: {
            it.validate()
        }
    }
}

@Validateable
class TestB {
    int c

    static constraints = {
        c min: 100
    }
}
```

One can simply resolve the bean and the attribute and delegate the rendering to the existing taglib.

```
import test.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.*

ValidationTagLib validationTagLib = ctx.getBean(ValidationTagLib)

renderErrorsWithNestedFields = { attrs, body ->
    def modifiedAttrs = attrs
    String[] path = attrs?.field?.split('\\.')
    if(path?.size() > 1) {
        Object resolvedBean
        resolvedBean = attrs.bean
        path[0..-2].each {
            //Some error handling would not hurt, but this is just a proof of concept
            resolvedBean = resolvedBean[it]
        }
        modifiedAttrs = new HashMap(attrs)
        modifiedAttrs.bean = resolvedBean
        modifiedAttrs.field = path.last()
    }
    validationTagLib.renderErrors (modifiedAttrs, null)
}


TestA a = new TestA(b:new TestB(c:3))
a.validate()
renderErrorsWithNestedFields([bean:a, field:'b.c'], null)
```

And this should render an error for violating the min constraint on c.